# Rejoin workstation to Samba Domain Controller. No Active Directory

Tags: windows-7, networking, samba, domain

So I might of goofed with this one. This current issue stemmed from a Trust relationship failing for the computer on the domain. Many places I read that to fix it you have to leave the domain and rejoin. Which later I found out I should of just changed my password...oops. At any rate...now when I try to rejoin the domain I get the following error:

> The join operation was not successful. This could be because an existing computer account having name "PCXXXXX" was previously created using a different set of credentials. Use a different computer name or contact your administrator to remove any stale conflicting account. The error was: Access is denied

My administrator removed the account from the Samba domain controller box but I still receive the error. I've restarted my computer at least twice. I'm not sure what more I should do to rejoin the domain. I should also add that we are not running Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

What fixed this issue was removing all check marks from the protocols in the network adapter setting except for the IPv4. Then restart the computer. After restarting recheck the same protocols and rejoin. This fixed the issue but I have no clue what was causing the initial problem.